# Linear dependence/independence and finding all solutions to the linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the matrix, $M = \begin{bmatrix}
-4 &1  &1 \\ 
 2&  0&1 \\ 
 0&1  &3 
\end{bmatrix}$. Are its columns linearly dependent or linearly independent vectors? Justify your answer and use it to find **all solutions** to the linear system $Mx=0$, where $x$ is a $3 \times 1$ real vector and $0$ is a $3 \times 1$ vector of zeros. Explain your answers.

**My solution:** To check linear independence $Mx=0 \implies x=0$.

So after doing the matrix algebra I am left with the following system of equations:

1. $-4x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=0$
2. $2x_{1}+x_{3}=0$
3. $x_{2}+3x_{3}=0$

From equation (2): I write $x_{3}=-2x_{1}$ and substitute away $x_{3}$ in equation (3) to get $x_{2} = 6x_{1}$.

Then I substitute away $x_{2}$ and $x_{3}$ in equation (1) and get $-4x_{1}+6x_{1}-2x_{1}=0$. So this just results in $0=0$.

Does this imply that the column vectors are not linearly independent? Also, are we going to have infinite solutions to this linear system as it could be the case that $Rank(M)<n=3$?

Comment: Do you know how to do Gauss-Jordan elimination?

Comment: No, but my instructor never taught me that and wants me to solve using the linear system of equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Gauss-Jordan method:**
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-4 &1  &1 \\ 
 2&  0&1 \\ 
 0&1  &3 
\end{bmatrix} \sim 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &1  &3 \\ 
 2&  0&1 \\ 
 0&1  &3 
\end{bmatrix} \sim \begin{bmatrix}
 2&  0&1 \\
0 &1  &3 \\ 
 0&0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$$
From here we can immediately tell this is a rank $2$ matrix.

---

**Triple product method:**
$$(-4,2,0) \cdot ((1,0,1)\times (1,1,3)) = (-4,2,0)\cdot(-1,-2,1) = 0$$
Therefore this matrix has rank $\lt 3$.

---

**Determinant method:**
$$\left|\begin{matrix}
-4 &1  &1 \\ 
 2&  0&1 \\ 
 0&1  &3 
\end{matrix}\right| = 0$$

Therefore this matrix has rank $\lt 3$.

---

**Substitution method (following your progress):**
$$\begin{cases} −4x_1+x_2+x_3=0 \\
2x_1+x_3=0\\
x_2+3x_3=0\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} −4x_1+x_2+x_3=0 \\
x_3=−2x_1\\
x_2=6x_1\end{cases} \iff \begin{cases} 0=0 \\
x_3=−2x_1\\
x_2=6x_1\end{cases}$$

Because the last system of equations has $3$ variables and only $2$ nontrivial equations it can't have a unique solution.  Because this is a homogeneous system it also can't have no solutions.  Therefor it must have infinitely many solutions.

---

A matrix that has rank $\lt$ the number of columns will have linearly **dependent** columns.  A matrix that has rank $=$ to the number of columns will have linearly **independent** columns.  It's not possible to have the rank of a matrix be larger than the number of columns.

Comment: So will the linear system $Mx=0$ have infinitely many solutions?

Comment: My latest edit should answer that question.

Comment: Cool. And also the column vectors are linearly dependent? It will help me if you mention it in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that the determinant method is the easiest by far. If the determinant of a square matrix is $0$, that is, it is a singular matrix then it is not full rank. So the rank will always be less than the number of columns.

Comment: That is correct.  I'd actually say the triple product is easiest, but the determinant is pretty easy too.